# Creating multiple plots with facet_wrap in separated windows

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, window

I created multiple plots with the function `facet_wrap` inside `ggplot`

```
tmp %>%
  ggplot( aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line( data=tmp %>% dplyr::select(-ID), aes(group=ID2), color="grey", size=0.5, alpha=0.5) +
  geom_line( aes(color=ID), color="#69b3a2", size=1.2 )+
  scale_color_viridis_d() +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position="none",
    plot.title = element_text(size=14),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  ) +
  ggtitle("Example") +
  facet_wrap(~ID)
```

And I correctly obtained multiple plots, all together in the window. How may I obtain these multiple plots separated, each one in a separated window?

Thanks

Comment: The premise of a `facet` is "all in one window". If you need them broken out, I think you have two options: (1) pre-filter your data and call `ggplot` individually for each one (optionally keeping the `facet_wrap`, since it will preserve most of the look); (2) consider using [`ggforce::facet_wrap_paginate`](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/facet_wrap_paginate.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your dataset based on the facetting variable, then pass the list of datasets to your plot function to create a series of plots. This is a simple example using the `iris` dataset.

```
library(ggplot2)

split_iris <- split(iris, iris$Species)

my_plot <- function(dat) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(title = unique(dat$Species))
}

lapply(split_iris, my_plot)
```